# how to configure openstack swift proxy with nginx

Tags: openstack-swift

How to configure open stack swift proxy with Nginx? Basically I want to upload large file to swift storage node through swift proxy without REST interface.

Is it possible to upload a file with out REST interface?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's impossible but it's **HIGHLY** undesirable. When you upload a file to swift it does a lot of operation to ensure durability and consistency. It would so much effort it's not a good idea.

What is your specific reason for that? On our cluster, we use Nginx doing reverse proxy to swift proxy without any big issue.

This conf can do the basics so Nginx will only reverse proxy to your swift proxy:

```
location / {
        root             html;
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
```

PS: the above exemple is really the essentials. You can improv it A LOT, according to your needs.

Comment: As per my knowledge, since we are using nginx, we need to configure swift proxy with nginx, I am not aware this can be done through reverse proxy. I am new to this, could you please share sample reverse proxy configuration with swift proxy using nginx.

Comment: See if this conf can help you. If you please, just let me know how it went.